# Press button, have a loading popup then change popup text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a button, and when someone clicks it I want there to popup a box (which I've already achieved) but before it popups I want some sort of loading circle with a text underneath, and that it popups after 3 secs.

Is this possible?

Current code:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<div class="btn">Win!</div>
</a>
<div id="light" class="white_content">Congratulations, you've won!<br>Claim your prize now by completing a short survey:<br>
<input type="submit" value="Complete Survey" onclick="location.href='http://mobverify.com/cl.php?id=5c78fd59851bf0c4867c008c9882d808'"> 
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></a>
</div>
```

Style of popup:

```
.white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 150%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: #2e3141;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this : http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/ .
It may help you!

Comment: You could check out [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), or another framework, which has build in support for modals (popup).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following CSS to your code.
CSS:-

```
.btn {
   width: 316px;
   height: 316px;
}
.btn:active{  background:url(http://www.cuisson.co.uk/templates/cuisson/supersize/slideshow/img/progress.BAK-FOURTH.gif) no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything?

Comment: Is there a way of increasin the time the loading thing is shown?

Comment: I need your JS file.Make a new fiddle and send to me,I'll help you @WobbaFam

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should make the loader image visible on click and use timeout function to execute the popup opening function after 3 seconds.

A small example:

```js
var timeout;

function startLoader(){
  document.getElementById('loader').className = '';
 timeout = setTimeout(openPopup, 3000);
  return false;
}

function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('loader').className = 'hidden';
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'none';
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  return false;
}
```

```css
.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #2e3141;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}

#loader {
  background: url(http://www.pointoffshore.com/SiteAssets/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="startLoader()">
  <div class="btn">Win!</div>
  <div id="loader" class="hidden"> </div>
  </div>
</a>
<div id="light" class="white_content">Congratulations, you've won!
  <br>Claim your prize now by completing a short survey:
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Complete Survey" onclick="location.href='http://mobverify.com/cl.php?id=5c78fd59851bf0c4867c008c9882d808'">
  <a href="#" onclick="closePopup()">close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you maybe help me over skype/teamviewer? Can't get it to work

Comment: sorry, office timings. We discuss it here if something you need as explaination